# Ubuntu only uses 768 MB instead of 1 GB ram

Tags: ubuntu, memory

The specs of my laptop and BIOS say that I have 1 GB (1024MB) of ram.

But when I use Ubuntu it says that I have only 768 MB.
Is there a way to use all the ram that I have?
I have Asus K53U laptop with Dual-core processor and AMD Radeon HD6250 graphics card.

Thanks

Comment: What's the laptop? Does it have shared video ram? Without more information, its pretty hard to answer definitively

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise about *what* says that you have only 768 MB? Where are you seeing this and what exactly are you seeing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shared Video Memory. Its likely your laptop has reserved 256mb of your 1gb for the integrated video card. In that case, no. Check your bios for the possibility of changing the specific amount put aside for VRAM. Note that it won't be zero in most cases. The only way around it is to disable the builtin video, if available.

Note:

> Furthermore, the built-in graphics card is an AMD Radeon HD 6310 with shared VRAM.

Your specific laptop can take up to 8 gigs of DDR3 memory, so you may want to upgrade if the memory saved for graphics processing is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

As [notebookcheck.com](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Asus-K53U-SX071V.74613.0.html) describes:

> AMD Radeon HD 6250: Integrated graphics card in the Ontario netbook processors (e.g. C-50 and C-30) featuring an UVD3 video decoder and **no dedicated memory**.

your laptop has no own graphics memory. So as by intel onboard graphics it uses your main memory instead.

You know video/graphic-calculations are so complex it requires a own process-unit (GPU). Even a own memory just for the graphic is needed. Most computers have its own graphics-ram so you can use your whole main memory just for other tasks.

But some weak GPUs doesn't need an extra fast dedicated memory, so your system memory shears with it instead:

[image]